# Is possible to read an Azure Databricks table from Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, metabase, azure-databricks

I have a table into an Azure Databricks Cluster, i would like to replicate this data into an Azure SQL Database, to let another users analyze this data from Metabase.

Is it possible to acess databricks tables through Azure Data factory?

Comment: Why not have Databricks perform the load to Azure SQL? https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#establish-connectivity-to-sql-server You could use ADF to just initiate the job.

Comment: @GregGalloway i have some non coding members on my team, they got used to these workflow tools, so Databricks seems a little hard for them, then i was looking for a solution inside ADF

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately not. Databricks tables are typically temporary and last as long as your job/session is running. [See here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html).

You would need to persist your databricks table to some storage in order to access it. Change your databricks job to dump the table to Blob storage as it's final action. In the next step of your data factory job, you can then read the dumped data from the storage account and process further.

Another option may be [databricks delta](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/delta/delta-intro.html) although I have not tried this yet...

Comment: I don't think delta tables are a good idea to do that. Maybe Parquet tables are the best solution.

Comment: Delta tables store old parquet files. so read it from another source can be a little hard

Answer (score 0):

If you register the table in the Databricks hive metastore then ADF could read from it using the ODBC source in ADF. Though this would require an IR. 
Alternatively you could write the table to external storage such as blob or lake. ADF can then read that file and push it to your sql database.